# ObjectInputStream custom classloader deserialization issue: resolveClass() not called

Tags: java, classloader, inputstream, deserialization

I have an `ObjectInputStream` and want to load classes with a custom `ClassLoader`.

Thus is created a subclass of `ObjectInputStream` that overrides the `resolveClass()` function.

Now my problem is that i want to change the `ClassLoader` during execution. But sometimes `resolveClass()` does not seem to be executed when I do `readObject()`on this stream. Then the class is loaded with the wrong `ClassLoader`.

Any idea why `resolveClass()` is not executed and how to solve this issue?

Comment: It is hard to answer something without any piece of significant parts of your code

Comment: `resolveClass()` is a standard function in ObjectInputStream and the only thing I do with the stream is execute `readObject()`.

Comment: how are you changing `ClassLoader` and how it is related with `ObjectInputStream` and deserialization?

Answer (score 2):

`resolveClass()` will be called once per class descriptor in the stream. I have no idea what would happen if you wrote multiple descriptors for the same full qualified class name - probably unspecified. The correct solution would be to use multiple streams (could be nested within one another).

Comment: Is it true that it also depends on the classloader of the sent object whether the call is done or not?

Comment: It is possible to add an annotation (not a Java language annotation, just some bytes) to the stream and use that to determine class loader. RMI for example does this unless disabled with the `"java.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly" system property (do set it!, the right one, not the incorrect string I put in the Java Secure Coding Guidelines). I can't off the top of my head remember what the sequence of calls is, or whether it's documented. It'll be in the code.

Answer (score 0):

From Java API doc for `ObjectInputStream.resolveClass()`:

> This method will be invoked only once for each unique class in the stream.

Possible quick&dirty fix:

Always call `reset()` on the `ObjectOutputStream` after sending.
This will reset the streams as if they were new and make them forget about having sent/received a class already.